# Excel - Count Cell only if 2 Other Cells are Blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

[image]

This is what my data looks like. I want to count anything in cells labeled "(Day) 1" but only if there is no data in cells labeled "(Day) 2" and "(Day) 3". Is that possible? Not sure if it will work but then I want to do the same for 2 and 3 days. Essentially, my issue is that I only need to count the day once, but if data is in cell 1 and 2, it's counting the days as 2 days (or if it's in all 3, it's 3 days count).

Count if, counting by hand, color coding the cells

Answer (score 0):

My coworker got it, just a little difficult but it works.

=IF((D22+E22+F22)>0,1,0)+IF((G22+H22+I22)>0,1,0)+IF((J22+K22+L22)>0,1,0)+IF((M22+N22+O22)>0,1,0)+IF((P22+Q22+R22)>0,1,0)+IF((S22+T22+U22)>0,1,0)+IF((V22+W22+X22)>0,1,0)

Comment: This code makes use of Excel treating blanks as zeros in formulas. It should work fine as long as there is no need to distinguish between blank cells and cells that contain zeros.

Comment: To make it work with zeros the terms summing the values for a day could be replaced with terms counting the values for a day: `(D22+E22+F22)` becomes `COUNT(D22:F22)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 365, you can take advantage of the ability to reshape an array.

For convenience in making the formula readable, I placed the data in a Table (named Table1).

`=SUM(IF(MMULT(WRAPROWS(IF(ISBLANK(Table1[[Mon 1]:[Sun 3]]),0,1),3),{1;1;1})>0,1,0))`

How it works:

- `IF(ISBLANK(Table1[[Mon 1]:[Sun 3]]),0,1)` results in a row vector that contains `0` if the cell is blank and `1` if the cell is filled
- `WRAPROWS(row vector,3)` converts the row vector into a 2d array with multiple 3 column rows (one row for each day)
- `MMULT(3 column array,{1;1;1})` uses matrix multiplication to effectively sum each row of the array resulting in a column vector (one value for each day; the number of cells filled in for that day)
- `IF(column vector > 0,1,0)` converts the vector to contain `1` if the day had any entry or `0` if the day had no entries
- `SUM(column vector)` gives us the final total number of days with entries

Answer (score 0):

The single-cell formula is

```
=LET(k;3;a;WRAPROWS(IF(ISBLANK(Table1[[Mo1]:[Su3]]);0;1);k);
  BYCOL(a;LAMBDA(c;SUMPRODUCT(c;IF(BYROW(a;LAMBDA(r;SUM(r)))=1;1;0)))))

or (depending on the list separator)

=LET(k,3,a,WRAPROWS(IF(ISBLANK(Table1[[Mo1]:[Su3]]),0,1),k),
  BYCOL(a,LAMBDA(c,SUMPRODUCT(c,IF(BYROW(a,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r)))=1,1,0)))))
```

It's applicable to any number of groups of any number of entries (k;3).

Table1 is the source table (select the range then press Ctrl+T).

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(k,3,a,WRAPROWS(IF(ISBLANK(A2:L2),0,1),k),SUM(N(BYROW(a,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))=1)))
```

A variant could be this formula. The range `A2:L2` can be changed according to the actual table size.